# How to enable NVIDIADeepstreamSDK Azure IoTEdge module to recieve messages from local rtsp?

Tags: tcp, rtsp, azure-iot-edge, local-network, nvidia-deepstream

I installed Azure IoTEdge on my Jetson nano and provisioned the IoTEdge runtime to the device using the security daemon file *at /etc/iotedge/config.yaml* .

I see that the status of the IoT Edge Daemon is active (running)
and all the 6 IoTEdge runtime modules that I'm using are running:
[console image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GvSF6.jpg)

-----------------NAME      --------------------                STATUS---------

- CameraTaggingModule    ----------      running
- DeepStreamAnalytics    ------------      running
- NVIDIADeepStreamSDK    -------      running
- azureblobstorageoniotedge  ---- running
- edgeAgent      --------------------------              running
- edgeHub             ----------------------------         running

But my NVIDIADeepStreamSDK module doesn't want to recieve messages from my RTSP Camera that is also in the same network as the Jetson, I see it logs of this module and it says:

> ```
> ERROR from src_elem0: Could not read from resource.
> Debug info: gstrtspsrc.c(5917): gst_rtsp_src_receive_response (): /GstPipeline:pipeline/GstBin:multi_src_bin/GstBin:src_sub_bin0/GstRTSPSrc:src_elem0:
> Could not receive message. (Timeout while waiting for server response)
> ```

The NVIDIADeepStreamSDK module can recieve messages succesfully if I use a public RTSP like [BigBugBunny rtsp](http://rtsp://wowzaec2demo.streamlock.net/vod/mp4:BigBuckBunny_115k.mov), so I guess the problem might has to do with some configuration of the local network. or should I make my RTSP Camera public? or should I provide some json file with DNS specificacion?, either case, what's the best way to approach this? Any sugestion is appreciated to make this work, thanks.

Comment: did you take a look at the documentation in this github repo? What did you try already? https://github.com/Azure-Samples/NVIDIA-Deepstream-Azure-IoT-Edge-on-a-NVIDIA-Jetson-Nano#view-the-processed-videos

Comment: @asergaz, Hi, sorry for the late response. 
I gave up with that IP camera, didn't know why never worked in my use case. At the end I realized that the DVR from my house also have a RTSP protocol... so I used that and worked.

I remember that tried following that tutorial that you mention[github.com/Azure-Samples/…](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/NVIDIA-Deepstream-Azure-IoT-Edge-on-a-NVIDIA-Jetson-Nano#view-the-processed-videos), saw the model doing the inference in those sample videos through VLC, but when switching to my camera, I got an error message in VLC.